# Why React can not auto batch in setTimeout before React18?

Tags: reactjs

Before React@18, every setState inside the setTimeout or async request resolve callback, will cause a re-render

```
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [flag, setFlag] = useState(false);

  function handleClick() {
    fetchSomething().then(() => {
      // React 17 and earlier does NOT batch these because
      // they run *after* the event in a callback, not *during* it
      setCount(c => c + 1); // Causes a re-render
      setFlag(f => !f); // Causes a re-render
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Next</button>
      <h1 style={{ color: flag ? "blue" : "black" }}>{count}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

but after React18, React can auto batch this case, React18 rewrite the entire event-delegate system ?